# Why is the address operator (&) important for an array being passed through a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, operators

I am having trouble understanding how the `&` operator works and its importance.

I found this example online:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a = 10;
  printf("\nValue of n is : %d" ,n);
  printf("\nValue of &n is : %u", &n);
}
```

Output :

```
Value of  n is : 10
Value of &n is : 1002
```

Firstly, why does the `&n` print out those two extra numbers?

Secondly, why is this important?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour. `%u` expects an `unsigned int`, not an `int *`.

Comment: There are no arrays anywhere in your question.

Comment: Nor is there a definition of `n`.

Comment: Find a book (or web site) that doesn't lie to you by suggesting that `void main()` is correct. It's `int main(void)`.

Comment: And print `'\n'` at the *end* of each output line, not at the beginning.

Comment: `printf("The address of n is %p\n", (void*)&n);`

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator is the "address of" operator. so `&a` means the `address of a`, not just the value of a.

What this is telling you is that the address of a is `1002` (or as dreamlax pointed out, quite possibly not the real address due to oddities with how printf is being used), even though the value is `10`. Note that there is no strict correlation between the two values, you could just as easily have `a=121765` and `&a=494260`.

Knowing the address of a variable allows you to manipulate that specific value/object the variable is "referring" or "pointing" to. If you wish for a function to manipulate that specific value/object rather than manipulate a copy, you should pass the variable's address.

Take the following code (not necessarily complete code):

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    doIt(a);
    printf("after doIt: %d", a);
    doItByReference(&a);
    printf("after doItByReference: %d", a);
}

void doIt(int val)
{
    val = 13;
}

void doItByReference(int *val)
{
    *val = 15;
}
```

Calling `doIt` passes the value held by `a`, and a new integer variable at a different address gets that value copied into it. The function is free to make any changes to this duplicate copy and no modifications will be seen in the original `a` variable.

However, calling `doItByReference` passes the address of `a`. Any changes made to the value at the given address will reflect as changes made to `a`.

This by itself is useful if you want to make changes to a given object and have those changes be reflected in the original copy. However, even if you don't want to modify a value in the original copy this is useful performance wise because you avoid having to copy any values. For a simple int which may be say 4 bytes (exact value isn't important), this is insignificant.

However, say you had a struct which was thousands or millions of bytes:

```
struct LargeStruct
{
    int buffer[134217728];
};

void doIt(LargeStruct buffer)
{
    // ... do something
}

void doItByReference(LargeStruct *buffer)
{
    // ... do something
}
```

This time, every call to `doIt` will have to copy the entire `LargeStruct` object which is millions of bytes, where-as a call to doItByReference simply uses the existing object and no copy is required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand what the operator does now. Could you perhaps tell me why it is important? What are the implications of not using the operator? Thank you.

Comment: Added two examples why using references would be useful. Hopefully I got the syntax right and didn't mix in any C++ specific stuff.

Comment: This was very informative. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Actually, using `%u` to print a pointer is undefined behaviour. The address is likely not `1002` at all, but probably a 64-bit address being interpreted as a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @dreamlax true, it could or could not be. Added a note, but part of the OP's original misunderstanding was around the & operator itself, not just misuse of the printf function.

Answer (score 0):

n is a variable.  It represents a value.
&n is a reference to n.  It represents the address in memory where n is store.

As to why it is important:

When you pass an array in C, the function is usually expecting a pointer.
(ie: int* as opposed to just int).
If you were to pass 'n' to the function, it would complain when compiling because the types don't match up (n=int, function expects int*).
If you pass in &n, however you are passing in an address to 'n' which is what the function expects.

Answer (score 0):

To print out an address in C, you normally should use `%p` in stead of `%u`.

Note `%p` prints out address in hexadecimal number.

Comment: Technically, `%p` prints a pointer in an implementation-specific manner. Usually it is hexadecimal but there is no requirement saying it must be.

Comment: Note that using `"%p"` the pointer should also be converted to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

The address of operator, `&`, returns the memory address of the following variable. This is important because:

1. it allows referring to large memory chunks (structures, arrays, dynamically allocated unstructured memory regions) with a light weight handle
2. it provides means to access internal representations of data structures
3. it allows us to process different types of data through the same interface